# Define a variable in .NET that is not shared between Web Service calls

Tags: .net, web-services, global-variables, static-variables

I need some way to define an Static variable in .NET don't shared between Web Service calls.

I have some web methods that recive the "username" (string) and password. After authenticate the user, i want to use "some global variable" that i can consult with this "username" when i need it. I can't use an Static variable, because static variable is shared between webmethods calls, and i need that this global variable not be shared between webservice calls (because they could be called by different users and i need every diference who is executing the methods). I also thought use an static dictionary with [thread id, username(string)], but thread ID is the same between difents calls...

So, any idea how define a global variable (or an static variable) that is not shared between Web Service calls?

Thx very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to share state within the current session. If so, you could use the HttpContext.Current.Session collection, but you'll need to add this to web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session is null (the web service has not authenticate), so i can't use Session.add. I need some way to define something like global varaible (static) that is not shared between calls to this web service or a way to identify one call to the web-service from another (some ID, token, o something like that), to create an static dictionary with ThisID-Variable to read "variable"

Comment: I see, so that tells me that you aren't hosting this WebService inside IIS.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing session management manually?

Imagine you send a unique session ID to the client once you authenticate the first request.

After that the client needs to pass this ID each time it invokes a service method, by adding a new parameter to each method or by using a new request header.

This way it's easy to implement the session variables in a static dictionary like you've mentioned above being the key this session ID.